# remote debug in Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on Windows Server 2008 x64 takes years to refresh process list

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, 64-bit, remote-debugging

When I remotely "Attach to Process" in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 to WS2008 (x64) computer running remote debugging monitor (both RTM and SP1), I see a huge number (30+) of entries saying:

```
<username> connected
```

Both TCP and authenticated mode are affected.

I think there is an entry per unique process name. Each connection attempt takes several seconds, so do your math - it takes years before I can see anything in VS2008 "Attach to Process" window.

I'm aware of workaround: I could just set up remote debugging with "Attach to Process" in project properties, but wtf? Such problem was never an issue in WS2003. Is there a patch I could apply to operating system, or firewall rule or something, which would fix such annoying behavior?